# Odds calculation drawing 3 cards

Tags: probability, card-games, gambling

I've had a few questions here wich helped me out greatly.
i'd like some advice again , this time my problem is probability based.

As a programming excercice I'm using a normal 52 deck of cards, and blackjack rules (J-Q-K = 10 , A = 1 or 11)
We draw 3 cards in order.

I want to calculate how often my total sum of the 3 cards is 15.
The way i have been going about is, is calculating the chance of all individual possibilities that makes up 15.

This would be :

A-A-3 , A-10-4,  A-9-5,  A-8-6 , A-7-7

10-3-2

9-4-2 , 9-3-3

8-5-2, 8-4-3

7-6-2 , 7-5-3,  7-4-4

6-6-3, 6-5-4

5-5-5

for a total of 16 possible combinations to make a total of 15.
so what i do right now :

- calculate the chance of each instance to occure , for example

TOA = Total amount of

A-A-3 = ((TOAAces/CardsLeft) * (TOAAces-1/CardsLeft - 1) * (TOAThrees /CardsLeft-2)) * 3

A-10-4 = ((TOAAces/CardsLeft) * (TOAValueTens/CardsLeft - 1) * (TOAFours/CardsLeft-2)) * 6

all the way to 555

5-5-5 = ((TOAFives/CardsLeft) * (TOAFives-1/CardsLeft - 1) * (TOAFives-2/CardsLeft-2)) * 1

add these values up , and voila , probability of a total value of 15, right?

**here's my question :**
I am unsure if my times 3,6 and 1 in above examples are right, they are supposed to represent the amount of possibilities i can draw the 3 cards (A-A-3, A-3-A,3-A-A).

Should i count every value 6 times for every possible possibility i can draw the 3 cards?
Is the above example correct? I feel like the math should check out on this , but it doesn't from what i've found.

If somebody could explain to me what i'm doing it wrong, you'd save me all alot of grief.. thanks !
Any suggestions or help would be appreciated :)

**Additional advanced question :**

What if i wanted to calculate the chance that the 15 was suited (all same suit)
Could i do the same , but calculate the chance of getting above values per suit?

You are heroes!

Comment: Your factors of $1$, $3$, and $6$ are correct.  There is only one way to arrange three identical numbers, $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to arrange three numbers if two of them are the same since such an arrangement is determined by the positions of the repeated number, and $3!$ ways to arrange three distinct numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first add all possibilities of the event summing to 15 and then divide by exhaustive number of possibilities in the sample space.

A) Here exhaustive number of possibilities to draw 3 cards is $52C3$. Please note that a draw of {A,2,3} or {2,A,3} is considered the same. We have to keep this in mind as we build possibilities for our event (which I saw you did correctly as you described in the question).

B) Now coming to the event of 3 cards summing to 15.

i) Case of a draw of {9,2,4} - the number of possibilities = $4C1 . 4C1 
 . 4C1$ = 64 (as there are four each of 9, 2 and 4 in the pack)

ii) Case of a draw of {9,3,3} - the number of possibilities = $4C1 . 4C2$ = 24 (as you need to draw two 3's from four 3's)

iii) similarly, case of a draw of {5,5,5} - the number of possibilities = $4C3$ = 4

iv) now take a case of {10,2,3} - the number of possibilities = $16C1 . 4C1 . 4C1$ = 256. This is because your rule says 10, J, Q, K (in total 16 cards) are all considered 10.

Please do the rest of the cases on this line. All cases summing to 15 will follow one of the above 4 patterns. For example, {A,A,3} will follow (ii).

Once you are done, add all possibilities of summing to 15 that you got in each of the cases and divide by $52C3$.

Comment: I will do that math and come back to this comment when i'm done - Could you tell me how my math is wrong though?

Comment: @dimitri gevaert I do not see your math wrong for a few examples you have given. It will work. But then you had a question on whether you should multiply the numerator by 3 and 6 or not. You have to. The reason you have to because you have duplicates in denominator too as you are doing 52x51x50 instead of $52C3$. Please read through my working and it should become clear. If any doubts, let me know.

Comment: I did the math , but my results are slightly of from what's correct, think i made a slight miscount somewhere though.
I'll keep you posted!

Ps. i've had more clarity using your examples than anywhere else online , thank you for that.

Comment: Do you get $0.051946$? Please note there are 16 cards of 10 (10,J,Q,K) and you have two cases A-10-4 and 10-3-2 where 10 comes.

Comment: I feel like my math is off , but i think ive figured out why.     in above example 2 (9-3-3) i use the math you gave me : 4c1 * 4c2 , but that's not completely correct... since the cards are drawn sequentially, i assume this changes the math to 4c1 * 4c1 * 3c1 for this case..... Sorry about the crappy text , commenting doesnt allow much formats.

Comment: Please feel free to comment if i'm wrong or explain what's up :) you're a lifesaver!

Comment: $4C2$ gives you 6 whereas $4C1.3C1$ gives you 12. There are duplicates in $4C1.3C1$. Take an example of S3 (3 of Spade) and C3 (3 of Club). Say case 1 is when you pick S3 first ($4C1$) and then C3 next ($3C1$). Now let's go to case 2 and say you pick C3 first ($4C1$) and you can still pick S3 next as you do 3C1. So now you have a situation where you did both {S3, C3} and {C3, S3}. That is a duplicate.

Comment: Ok , i did the math again with what i thought was right , and now it's completely off , back to the last step then :)

Comment: For (9-3-3), if you are going with $4C1.4C1.3C1$, you can do that but then you will have to multiply by 3 and divide by $52.51.50$ instead of $52C3$. Like you had mentioned in your question.

Comment: When you say it's off, do you know what the right answer is?

Comment: i get a total of 1616 combinations , out of 22100 outcomes, wich results in a 0.05176471, not exactly the percentage you've given --- a little more context , i've done chance for alot of numbers , including 18-19-20-21 ect , which information i've used to compare my math.

Comment: Could you recall how much combinations you had? that way i can check where mine is off , it seems like you had abit MORE combinations then me. which bothers me as i can't figure out where i went wrong.

Comment: 1616 will give you 0.07312, no? I get 1148 i) two cases with 10 in it  - 256 combinations * 2 cases ii) all 3 cards different (other than two cases with 10 in it) - 64 * 8  iii) Two cards same - 24 * 5 iv) All same - 4*1

Comment: Oh sorry , i was looking at the wrong numbers , i have 1144 combinations to 22100 outcomes

Comment: So somehow , i am 4 of your count.

Comment: I figured out my mistake and now come out to your answer , thank you very much kind sir!

Comment: Any chance you could doublecheck something for me?

I did the same for a total of 19 combinations posibble :  A A 7 --
 A 10 8--
 A 9 9--
 A 2 6 --
 A 3 5--
 A 4 4 --
 2 7 10 --
 2 8 9 --
3 8 8 --
3 7 9 --
3 6 10 --
4 9 6  --    
4 8 7  --    
5 7 7--    
5 10 4--       
5 9 5 --      
5 8 6--, using the above solution , i come up to a 7,31 chance for a 19 (1616/22100) , seems about right?